# Support only https in Load Balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have created a load balancer on `GCP`. It supports both `http` and `https`. I want to change it so that it supports only `https`. I considered referring to this document https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect but it seems to create two separate load balancers.

As I already have a load balancer which is currently serving both `http` and `https` traffic, I'll prefer that I change the existing one. How could I do it?

Load balancer set up looks like this

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The load balancer connects with two backend services

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I suppose I should add a host and path rules but I can't figure out what should be the rule to redirect all `http` traffic with 301.

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Would `host` be the domain name of my web application (eg. [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com))?

The path rule takes url path but not url scheme (http). How do I specify that do redirect only for http traffic?

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

Comment: If your load balancer is for a public website, do not disable HTTP. The default today is HTTP when a user enters a url without a protocol. Without an HTTP listener your website will appear to be down. Implement the HTTP -> HTTPS redirect in your backend and configure both HTTP and HTTPS frontend listeners.

Comment: Agree John - the intent is to keep `http` ON but redirect `http` traffic to `https` using `301`. But I can't figure out how to configure that in my current load balancer. I tried creating another load balancer for `http` as per the link in my question. That should redirect the requests to `https` load balancer but so far it is not working. Maybe it takes some time for the configurations to take effect.

Comment: Reread my comment. Configure the redirect in your backend.

Comment: got it working. I thijnk it just took time to configure. Removed the http frontend rule from my existing https load balancer and created a new one as per the link to route http traffic to https

Comment: I still recommend configuring the redirect action in your backends. Configuring an additional load balancer to just redirect seems like an expensive solution unless your backends cannot process HTTP headers. Post an answer with how you solved this problem so the question is complete.

Comment: I am using `Play` framework. Do I understand correctly that your recommendation is that I use redirection within `Play` as opposed to having a separate load balancer?

Comment: I do not have experience with that framework, so I cannot answer.

Comment: @manu, we see your project ID in screenshots, please edit for security purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are using GKE, so this setup might be different.

On your Ingress you must use the following annotation as per [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress-xlb#disabling_http)

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
```

This will tell GCP to only use HTTPS when creating your Load Balancer, please note that this (as per today) will only work when creating your Ingress deployment, if you edit this onto an existing Ingress it will be accepted but not be deployed.

After that, you can use the [guide](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect#partial-http-lb) you were using to deploy a secondary HTTP Load Balancer (with the same external IP address) in order to route your requests for HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks. I am on `GKE`. I didn't keep the `kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"` as I didn't want to block `http` completely and I had only one load balancer.